# Textbox with password mode lose value

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radtextbox

I am using an `ASP TextBox` and a `Telerik RadTextBox` in my asp.net webform. I know the The both the controls clear its value after each postback and this is by design due to security reasons.

In my scenario both the controls are ajaxified. Still the `ASP TextBox` and `RadTextBox` loses it value on `ajax request (partial postback)`.

So my doubt, is this expected? Will the textbox lose value on both full postback as well as on ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ASP.NET Textbox and Telerik Textbox will be rendered as `<input type="password" />`. `<input type="password" />` is treated a little bit different than the other controls as it contains sensitive information. On every postback they are forcefully cleared.

But if there is some requirement then you can store the information and set it back.

```
string Password = txtPassword.Text;
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", Password);
```

**Note: But I really don't recommend it.**

Comment: On every postback they are forcefully cleared. What about on an ajax request or partial postback?

Comment: Yes! Every postback includes Partial Postbacks as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax based function calling never causes Data loss or refresh happened in client side. I think it may be happened due to object you have selected for ajax calling. For eg:

```
<input type="button" id="Submit">
<input type="submit" id="Submit">
```

They exhibit different behavior in ajax calling.